# i have a problem with lua eclipse ide some one can help me?

Tags: eclipse, lua

you can see the problem here

[image: 1]

I started programming in lua and I wanted to make a simple program. the problem I’m experiencing is that if I enter if functions within the code the program won’t start and auto ends at startup

as you can see from image the compiler said "terminated"

update: now the code looks like this

```
local function main()
print("insert four binary number for color encryption")
a,b,c,d = io.read("*n","*n","*n","*n")
a=n
b=n
c=n
d=n
end
main()
if(a == 1){
print(white)        
} 
then
print(black)
end
```

i moved the if under the main() at the end

now the console gives `nil` follow by

```
Exception in thread "main" com.naef.jnlua.LuaRuntimeException: ...t-win32.win32.x86_64\workspace\luabello\src\main.lua:10: attempt to call a boolean value
    at com.naef.jnlua.LuaState.lua_pcall(Native Method)
    at com.naef.jnlua.LuaState.call(LuaState.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.ldt.support.lua51.internal.interpreter.JNLua51Launcher.run(JNLua51Launcher.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.ldt.support.lua51.internal.interpreter.JNLua51Launcher.main(JNLua51Launcher.java:143)
```

update 2: now the code looks like this

```
local function main()
print("insert four binary number for color encryption")
a,b,c,d = io.read("*n","*n","*n","*n")

end
main()
a=n
b=n
c=n
d=n
if(a <= 1){
print(white)        
} 
then
else
print(black)
end
```

it gave me another error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.naef.jnlua.LuaRuntimeException: ...t-win32.win32.x86_64\workspace\luabello\src\main.lua:11: attempt to compare nil with number
    at com.naef.jnlua.LuaState.lua_pcall(Native Method)
    at com.naef.jnlua.LuaState.call(LuaState.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.ldt.support.lua51.internal.interpreter.JNLua51Launcher.run(JNLua51Launcher.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.ldt.support.lua51.internal.interpreter.JNLua51Launcher.main(JNLua51Launcher.java:143)
```

Comment: You're not calling the `main` function. Is that `main()` call supposed to be after the function definition? Also, please don't post screenshots here. Instead, copy and paste your code into the question.

Comment: the local function main() and the main() at the end are auto generated code form the compiler itself. you are right but i need a screenshot to visualized the problem in the mind of a reader

Comment: I don't see how the compiler can add Lua code to your file. Did the IDE add extra code when you tried to compile or run your program?

Comment: no, when you create a lua project the complier add those line automatically do the same thing with eclispe java ide

Comment: I think the problems you're having can be fixed by learning about syntax from a tutorial. There are a few tutorials here: http://lua-users.org/wiki/LearningLua

Comment: Do not edit your question to be a completely different question, just ask it as a new question. If you feel context from this question is necessary for the new question you can link it in the new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your if condition is probably not what you expect it to be,

```
if(a == 1){
print(white)        
}
```

this will attempt to call the result of `a == 1` and pass for the first param `{print(white)}` then evaluate if that is true, but you will get an error as you can not call the result of `a == 1` as it is a boolean value.

I believe you meant:

```
if(a == 1) then
    print(white)        
else
    print(black)
end
```

---

Also you are setting `a,b,c,d` twice,

1. to the result of `io.read("*n","*n","*n","*n")`
2. to `n` which is not defined so the values are set to `nil`

Comment: are `white` and `black` defined? or did you mean you wanted to print the string `white` and the string `black`? if that is the case you need to do `print("white")` and `print("black")`

Comment: well that is embarssing becuse i am a complete id.... i need to add "" but in princible i want to use special characters form windows chracters map but i dont know how to insert they

Comment: i made those mistakes beacuse i start with java